# Where can I find an explanation of the various details on vehicle HUDs?

Tags: battlefield-3

All of the different vehicles have complicated HUDs that provide all sorts of useful information. Some of this information I've been able to discover through trial and error (i.e. gun position in the rectangle at the bottom of the attack helicopter gunner view), but a lot of the other HUD details are lost on me.

I hear that you can see jet altitude, but I haven't been able to determine which number on the HUD corresponds to it.

Am I wrong in assuming that there might be useful data in vehicle HUDs, if I was able to read it? Has anyone done a useful guide on what info the HUDs display?

Answer (score 7):

Here are is an explanation of the Jet and Copter HUDs (via [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/ld6ax/bf3_jet_hud_explained/) and [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/ldfw4/bf3_heli_hud_explained/))

[image: Jet HUD] 
F/A 18 Super Hornet:
[See above full sized.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv5FD.jpg)

[image: Copter HUD]
Mil MI-28 Havoc:
[See above full sized.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAKEQ.jpg)

As an additional note, aligning the I-beam with the vertical bit of the crosshair ensures that your rockets will fly to their target. This also works by aligning the 'O' in between the two | | in the Sideslip Indicator (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAKEQ.jpg) above).

Comment: This is awesome! Are there similar diagrams for tanks/gunner seats (for helis and tanks)?

Answer (score 2):

There is really nothing too useful there to be honest. The only extra hud feature I find useful is in the jets the cross-hair circle makes it easy to lead enemy jets with the guns. The HUD is mostly supplemented for realism, but I guess the altitude could be handy...I just use my better judgement while flying.

Comment: Can you expand on using the crosshair circle to lear enemy jets?

Comment: Watch this video and about halfway through he shows you how to lead a jet with the circle. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Wd6uaynTg0w . Essentially when tailing an enemy you want to shoot where he is going not where he is, due to bullet travel time and his travel speed. So if you keep the enemy jet in the right radius of the circle it makes it easier to lead them and shoot them down.